# Phonon Calculation (IR Spectrum) in Quantum Espresso

Tags: quantum-espresso

I have been following the example laid out in: https://github.com/maxhutch/deprecated-quantum-espresso/blob/master/PHonon/examples/example15/reference/zno.ph.in

Here, the input file for the phonon calculation is:

```
Normal modes for Wurtzite
 &inputph
  tr2_ph=1.0d-14,
  prefix='ZNO',
  amass(1)=65.409,
  amass(2)=15.999,
  outdir='/home/larrucea/tmp'
  epsil=.false.,
  trans=.true.,
  asr=.true.
  fildyn='dmat.zno'
 /
 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

I am confused by the final line (which is needed for the calculation to work).

```
 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

What is the meaning of this line? What other values can/should it take?

Comment: https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/423/5

Comment: [The QE documentation](https://www.quantum-espresso.org/Doc/INPUT_PH.html#idm197) specifies the input format for Phonon calculations. This last line seems to be "The phonon wavevector, in units of 2pi/a0
(a0 = lattice parameter)."